# Discord Settings Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, discord

I treid this code why is "Method Not Allowed" ? ,
Token Wrong? Post Wrong? Header Wrong?
I dont have Idea.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WvHkkKtv9ANE3dlD5X6c7tttFcpKj6dn/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJUuns2FEoRk1WaZClDLx8PzBeg1xba3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

"405 Method not allowed" generally means exactly what it says: That the HTTP method you're using is not accepted for the operation you're trying to do.

You're sending a POST request. While I haven't used Discord's API myself, [a quick search](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360054595731-Setting-Custom-Status-Programmatically) gives me the impression that setting a `custom_status` with `/users/@me/settings` requires the method to be PATCH.

[Here's a StackOverflow question which answers how to send a PATCH request with PHP/CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451401/how-do-i-make-a-patch-request-in-php-using-curl):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
```